# Importing text file to Access database in Windows 7

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to import data from a text file to Access 2007 and 2010, delimited by vertical bar. I use Import Text Wizard of MS Access, but when I try to import it after choosing appropriate delimiter (preview looks fine), I get the following error:

**The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship. Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.**

There are no primary keys, nor relationships, as it is just a text file. I was able to insert this text file in Windows XP, but the problem arises in Windows 7. I was able to successfully export the data into Excel. I also set Indexed to No in Field Options of Import Text Wizard, but that didn't help either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I couldn't find any useful info anywhere.

Edit: I tried inserting into new and existing tables, even a new database (accdb and mdb format), every time I get the same error.

Edit2: I opened the text file in WordPad, and saved it again as txt file, the Access didn't generate any error. The previous txt file didn't show the new lines, but Access was still aware where each record ends, and preview looked fine. The new text file specifically shows new lines (each record separately). If someone has a suggestion about how to overcome this issue without creating a new txt file, please let me know

Comment: Do you import into a new table or into an existing one? The error is not about the text file, but about the table you insert the data into.

Comment: I tried both. Even inserting into a completely empty database and new table generates identical error.

Comment: Huh. Weird. In the import wizard, there is a page where you select whether Access should add a primary key, or use an imported column, or none. Which did you use? Have you tried letting Access add a Autonumber column?

Comment: Yes, I tried all 3 options, nothing seems to solve the issue

Comment: Can you create a minimal set of data that reproduces the problem, and post it? Using this: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html  --- edit: the formatter is not needed, since you have | as separator.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the file contains some customer information. But I think I've found the problem, but not quite sure how to solve it using a better way. Apparently, my old text file didn't have a new line characters, but the Access somehow was aware when to start a new line. So I opened the text file in WordPad, which shows the new lines, and saved it again as txt file. Now the Access imported without any problem

Comment: Well, try to describe the problem, then. :-)

Comment: See the comment above :) It is very weird, I am just opening and saving the text file again, without editing it, but using a different text editor, and now it works. I didn't have this problem with XP though

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support. Though if you have any idea/suggestion regarding this "new line problem", I'm all ears

Comment: Perhaps your original file is created on a UNIX (or similar) system and has only LF as newline character, while Windows wants a CRLF. WordPad seems to automatically convert this. And perhaps on the XP machine there was a different "text" database driver that recognized the format automatically.

Comment: It looks like it is the case. Thanks again very much, I'm sorry I can't upvote or accept your answer because of the low reputation. Do you have any idea regarding how to overcome this without saving it as another file, as I might lost some data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is anything you can do except convert the file to Windows CRLF format.

Although I wouldn't use WordPad for this, but [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/).
It has an explicit command for this: **Edit -> EOL conversion**, and you can be fairly sure that it won't change anything else in your file (I wouldn't be so sure about WordPad).

Actually most text editors that are more sophisticated than Notepad have a command for this, I think. :)